# Shuffle phase lasts too long Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I'm having a MR job in which shuffle phase lasts too long.

At first I thought that it is because I'm emitting a lot of data from Mapper (around 5GB). Then I fixed that problem by adding a Combiner, thus emitting less data to Reducer. After that shuffle period did not shorten, as I thought it would.

My next idea was to eliminate Combiner, by combining in Mapper itself. That idea I got from [here](http://apmblog.dynatrace.com/2012/01/25/about-the-performance-of-map-reduce-jobs/), where it says that data needs to be serialized/deserialized to use Combiner. Unfortunately shuffle phase is still the same.

My only thought is that it can be because I'm using a single Reducer. But this shouldn't be a case since I'm not emitting a lot of data when using Combiner or combining in Mapper.

Here are my stats:

[image]

Here are all the counters for my Hadoop (YARN) job:

[image]

I should also add that this is run on a small cluster of 4 machines. Each has 8GB of RAM (2GB reserved) and number of virtual cores is 12 (2 reserved).

[image]

These are virtual machines. At first they were all on a single unit, but then I separated them 2-2 on two units. So they were sharing HDD at first, now there are two machines per disk. Between them is a gigabit network.

And here are more stats:

Whole memory is occupied

[image]

CPU is constantly under pressure while the job is run (the picture shows CPU for two consecutive runs of same job)

[image]

My question is - why is shuffle time so big and how to fix it? I also don't understand how there was no speedup even though I have dramatically reduced the amount of data emitted from Mapper?

Comment: hard to tell without getting more numbers: what is the exact size of the map output? how big is the network link between your server (bandwidth)? can you use more than a single reducer (thus avoiding a possible bandwidth bottleneck)?

Comment: Thank your for your comment, I have edited my question. I really have no idea why would it be so slow. I have mostly developed on a single machine, so I'm learning about running jobs on cluster, but I see no reason for this problem. It would be very hard (if not impossible) to split reducer, but the thing is, I see no job for it.

Comment: difficult to tell why it takes so long for 5mb, anything unusual you can see in ambari? like a pegged CPU? can you go to the logs of the reduce container and find anything?

Comment: @ThomasJungblut Well, the memory is full. CPU not that much, I would say. Logs in reducer don't show anything unusual (to me). I have added more stats.

Comment: Are you swapping? If the memory is full, then that kinda explains why it is too slow ;)

Comment: What do you mean am I swapping? Isn't that done automatically? Well, I was thinking that 4 machines with 6GB (of usable) RAM would be enough to process arround 5GB of data? Am I wrong?

Comment: You should simply not run at 100% memory usage on your slave. You probably need to reduce your allocation to the containers. Try 4gb?

Comment: Nope...After reducing the container size to 4GB time needed for the job is same and memory goes up from 98% to 100%, so it doesn't help. I think that this percentage is for the amount of memory reserved for containers (which is 6GB per node), so 8GB is not occupied, but 6GB. I could possibly add another machine, or something like that, but I have feeling that there is a bigger problem than the amount of memory available.

Answer (score 0):

Few observations :

1. For a job of 30 mins, the GC time is too high (Try reusing objects rather creating a new one for each call in map()/Reduce() method)
2. Average map time is TOOOOO hight , 16 mins what are you doing in ur map ?
3. YARN memory is 99% , this signifies you are running too many services on your HDP cluster and RAM is not sufficient to support those many services.
4. Please increse YAN container memory, please give at least 1 GB.
5. This looks like a GC + overscheduled cluster problem